# how to resolve this Timeout exception in WAS 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere-7, corba, timeoutexception

I am getting below time out exception from my java program.

```
 [4/10/14 6:27:02:859 CDT] 00000004 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0006W: Transaction 000001454B5F86E80000000100007366C376DBAB11CE46C9F72BF0EF6B270F9458C6856F000001454B5F86E80000000100007366C376DBAB11CE46C9F72BF0EF6B270F9458C6856F00000001 has timed out after 300 seconds.
    [4/10/14 6:27:02:862 CDT] 00000004 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread with which the transaction is, or was most recently, associated was Thread[ORB.thread.pool : 3,5,main]. The stack trace of this thread when the timeout occurred was: 
        java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:196)
        com.ibm.rmi.iiop.OutCallDesc.waitForResponse(OutCallDesc.java:58)
        com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.getCallStream(Connection.java:2341)
        com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.send(Connection.java:2295)
        com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ClientRequestImpl.invoke(ClientRequestImpl.java:338)
        com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:424)
        com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:1122)
        com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:708)
        com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:1152)
        org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(ObjectImpl.java:484)
        com.facade._ARFacade_Stub.getLetter(_ARFacade_Stub.java:1109)
        com.delegate.ARDelegate.getLetter(ARDelegate.java:730)
        com.impl.ARImpl.invokeAR(ARImpl.java:360)
```

I observed that i have to increase the timout of the transaction. but i dont know my assumption is correct or not...

could you please guide me to take corrective action for this timeout exception...?

or do i need to take look on _ARFacade_Stub.java,AReceivableDelegate.java that are mentioned in the error log...

Comment: Did you manage to figure this one out by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for exactly why your timeout is occurring is hard for us to do. You need to look at what is done in the transaction and see if something just takes a long time or too long. If it takes too long you need to see what goes wrong there, but that is hard for us to help you with given the above description. Especially look at if you are running out of resources and the thread that times out is waiting for that resource but is not able to get it for a long time or ever.

It could also be the case that whatever you are doing is taking a long time and that is normal. According to your tags you are using WebSphere Portal and there are a lot of things that may take more than five minutes. If that is the case you can increase the transaction timeout values.

Here is how to change these values:

1. Log in to the administrative console.
2. Navigate to the Transaction service panel.
3. WebSphere Application Server 7.0: Click Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name > Container Services > Transaction Service.
4. Increase the Total transaction lifetime timeout. The default value is 120.
5. Increase the Maximum transaction timeout. The default value is 300 seconds.
6. Stop and restart WebSphere Application Server.

These steps are taken from IBM InfoCenter

Comment: Actually i am using one select query inside my getLetter() method...it is a hibernate query...noting inside getLetter()...

Comment: Sounds like a simple query, I would check and see if the query actually takes that long or if you run out of database connections and the timeout is because of waiting for a connection.

Comment: Wouldn't help, I can not determine from here if and why it would take a long time. You need to monitor the time it takes for the query to execute and the number of available connections for the database.